# Intrinsically proving a singularity is rational

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory, algebraic-surfaces

In general, how to prove a variety has rational singularities intrinsically? i.e., don't use the Artin's criterion concerning the exceptional locus. And what kinds of varieties have only rational singularities? I've read a proof of classification of normal cubic surfaces (paper of Bruce and Wall), but their method is quite concrete, is there any way to prove the fact that a normal cubic surface which is not a cone can only contain rational singularities without using the classification of du Val singularities?

Comment: The singularity of a cubic cone is not rational!

Comment: I'm sorry! I mean normal cubic surfaces which are not cones.

Answer (score 2):

For a cubic surface $X$ this is easy: for any resolution $f:\hat{X}\rightarrow X$ the surface $\hat{X}$ must be rational (the singular points of $X$ are double points since cones are excluded; project from a double point). Thus $H^i(\mathcal{O})$ vanish for $X$ and $\hat{X}$, and $i=1,2$. From the Leray spectral sequence for $f$ one gets $R^1f_*\mathcal{O}_{\hat{X}}=0$, which is one of the characterizations of rational singularities.

It is hard to give a precise answer in the general case: it depends what you know about your variety and its resolution.

Comment: Thanks! BTW, can you recommend some references about surface singularities?

Comment: Vast program! You might try [these notes](https://www.renyi.hu/~nemethi/JEGYZET.ps).